# Inno Setup Section [Run] with condition

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I need a help with condition in `[Run]`. If it's possible...
I need to run a command that depends on a condition.

Like this:

```pascal
if (UserPage.Values[0] = 'NC') then // FileName: {sys}\inetsrv\appcmd.exe; Parameters: "set......"
```

Or other way to do it.

Regards.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are looking for the [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck):

```
[Run]
FileName: "{sys}\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"; Parameters: "set......"; Check: ShouldRun
```

```pascal
[Code]

function ShouldRun: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (UserPage.Values[0] = 'NC');
end;
```